# How to protect GAE db without using SSL when client is Android

Tags: android, database, security, google-app-engine, ssl

I just started to learn GAE and noticed that there can be access to my servlets from anywhere.
My GAE is only used by an Android app to store user data and to keep track of users and GCM regId's.

The expensive GAE SSL implementation in this stage is overkill for me so I need advice on alternative solutions. I read many answers about this and and they all using some form of HTTP login page or other browser related access. I use com.android.volley in my Android app.

Any advice would be grate.

Answer (score 2):

For `*.appspot.com` domains, SSL is available. Please refer to the following for configuring your application : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

You could also look at Google Cloud Endpoints to expose your APIs and ensure that you enable security for the different methods that you expose. You can also specify the Client Ids that the Android Application will be using to authenticate itself to your Endpoints implementation. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/ '

Check out Android Endpoints client too : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

Comment: I Will learn the Google Cloud Endpoints tictactoe-android sample and see if it's what i need.

Comment: I managed to run this tic-tac-toe example but looks little complicated for me. Is it possible to achieve the same using jersey?

Comment: After reading I found this [Google Cloud Endpoints tutorial](http://pisarenko.net/blog/2013/08/29/build-an-android-app-using-google-cloud-endpoints-with-oauth/). I think it's easier then going through the google tutorial tic-tac-to.(found no walktrough). This tutorial is using OAuth2. Is this what you had in mind for me?

Comment: Your [in-depth 7 part](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial looks grate